# HTML Timetable adding day breaks the formatting

Tags: html, timetable

We had this timetable built for our gym. The company that built the timetable has gone bankrupt. We need some help adding Sundays to the timetable. When I try to copy "Saturday" and rename it to Sunday and add "Sunday" to the table, the timetable formatting acts weird and the classes I put in under "Sunday" show up all over the place. Please help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1AmkhgnPlz7U19GTy1ic2VQd0U&ver=0.1" />
<style>
.sqs-block-code {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#sqs-timetable {
  margin: left;
  width: 100%;
}
  
#sqs-timetable table {
  border-collapse: initial;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
#sqs-timetable table th {
  width: 10%;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1AmkhgnPlz7Rk1YNlJ1NlZ0dzg&ver=0.1"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    var colorType = {
      'Beginner Class': { bgcolor: '#549ed1', bghover: 'grey' },
      'BJJ Inter & Adv': { bgcolor: '#5C5C63', bghover: 'grey' },
      'SW Inter & Adv': { bgcolor: '#E3655B', bghover: 'grey' },
      'Yoga Class': { bgcolor: '#E29804', bghover: 'grey' },
      'Open Mat': { bgcolor: '#66666E', bghover: 'grey' },
    };
    var config = {
      monday: [
        { type: 'Beginner Class', time: 'Brazilian Jiu Jitsu <p>Fundamentals</p> 12:00~13:30' },
        {},
      ],
      tuesday: [
        { type: 'BJJ Inter & Adv', time: 'Advanced Sparring<p> (Blue belt) </p> 12:00~13:30' },
        {},
      ],
      wednesday: [
        { type: 'Beginner Class', time: 'Thaiboxing <p>Fundamentals</p> 12:00~13:30' },
        {},
      ],
      thursday: [
        { type: 'Yoga Class', time: 'Basic Flow <p> For Everyone </p> 17:30~18:30' },
        {},
      ],
      friday: [
        { type: 'SW Inter & Adv', time: 'Intermediate <p> (6 Months)</p> 12:00~13:30' },
        {},
      ],
      saturday: [
        {type: 'Open Mat', time: 'Members Only <p> (Age 15 Years) </p> 14:00~16:00'},
        {},
      ]
    };
    setTimeTable(config, colorType);
  });
</script>
<div id="sqs-timetable">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">All Classes<span class="arrow"></span></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span id="all-events">All Classes</span>
  </div>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<div class="mobile"></div>
</div>
```

```js
/**
 * @plugin: Time Table
 * @version: 0.1
 * @website: Squareplugs.com
 * @description: Time Table Plugin for Squarespace
 * @author: Zeddicus Zu'l Zorander <jimenez.phillip.felicidario@gmail.com>
 */

eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
  e = function(c) {
    return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
  };
  if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
    while (c--) {
      d[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c)
    }
    k = [function(e) {
      return d[e]
    }];
    e = function() {
      return '\\w+'
    };
    c = 1
  };
  while (c--) {
    if (k[c]) {
      p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c])
    }
  }
  return p
}('7 1z(e,t){2 0===e?1r.1u("1F 1l 1m 1g."):2 0===t?1r.1u("1D 1l 1m 1g."):(P(e,t),$(M).L("1C",7(o,n){$("13 9:1i-N 9:1p-N(3)").1w("Q",7(){P(e,t),$(y).1x("Q")})}),$("13").L("1v","a",7(){$("13 9:1i-N 9:1p-N(3)").1w("Q",7(){P(e,t),$(y).1x("Q")})}))}7 P(e,t){g o=M.10.X,n=o.1s(1,o.q),i="",a=1;B(1===$("#k-j .8 .8-E 4").q){$.A(t,7(e,s){B(!(a<=K.H(t).q))14!1;B(o.q>0)g l=e===n?\'x="19"\':"";i+=\'<4 1c="\'+e+\'" \'+l+">"+e+"</4>",a++});g s=$("#k-j .8 .8-E");s.I(s.I()+i)}o.q>0&&("G-F"===n&&(n="1b 18"),$("#k-j .8 .16").I(n+\'<4 x="1d"></4>\')),$("#k-j .8 .8-E 4").L("1v",7(){g o=M.10.X,n=o.1s(1,o.q),i=$(y).1A("1c");14 $("#k-j .8 .8-E").12(),""===n&&"G-F"===i||n===i?!1:(M.10.X=i,$("#k-j W").12(),S(e,t,i),$("#k-j .8 .16").I($(y).1E()+\'<4 x="1d"></4>\'),$("#k-j .8 .8-E 4").1H(),$(y).1G("19"),$("#k-j W").1I(),2 0)}),$("#k-j .8").L("1y",7(){$("#k-j .8 .8-E").1B()}),$("#k-j .8").L("1M",7(){$("#k-j .8 .8-E").12()}),0===o.q||"1b 18"===n?S(e,t,"G-F"):S(e,t,n),1q(e)}7 1q(e){g t="";$.A(e,7(e,o){t+="<17>"+e.1S(0).1R()+e.1T(1)+"</17><1a>",$.A(o,7(e,o){K.H(o).q>0&&(2 0===o.U?t+="<V><4>"+o.5+"</4><9>"+o.w+"</9></V>":$.A(o.U,7(e,o){t+="<V><4>"+o.5+"</4><9>"+o.w+"</9></V>"}))}),t+="</1a>"}),$("#k-j .1U").I(t)}7 S(e,t,o){g n={};$.A(e,7(e,t){$.A(t,7(t,o){n[t]=2 0===n[t]?{}:n[t],n[t][e]=2 0===n[t][e]?{}:o,n[t][e]=o})});g i="",a={},s={},l=0,d="";$.A(n,7(e,n){$.A($.1o({},n),7(n,r){B(l++,"1J"===n&&(i+="<1t>"),2 0===r.U){g p="";B(p="G-F"===o?K.H(r).q>0&&2 0!==r.5&&2 0!==r.w&&2 0!==t[r.5]:K.H(r).q>0&&2 0!==r.5&&2 0!==r.w&&2 0!==t[r.5]&&r.5===o){g c="J: "+t[r.5].R,v="y.z.J=\'"+t[r.5].1h+"\';",b="y.z.J=\'"+t[r.5].R+"\';",m=2 0!==r.C&&r.C>0?r.C+1:0,h=r.w.1j("-")[0].1k();B(s[e]=!0,m&&"G-F"===o){1e(g u=1;m-1>=u;u++){g f=O(e)+u+""+l;a[f.15()]=!0,s[O(e)+u]=!0}i+=\'<D C="\'+m+\'" z="\'+c+\'" Y="\'+v+\'" 11="\'+b+\'">\'}T i+=\'<D z="\'+c+\'" Y="\'+v+\'" 11="\'+b+\'">\';i+=\'<9 x="1n"><4>\'+r.5+\'</4><9 x="1f"><4 x="w">\'+h+"</4></9></9></D>"}T s[e]=2 0===s[e]?!1:s[e],2 0===a[e+""+l]&&(i+="<D></D>")}T{g m=2 0!==r.C&&r.C>0?r.C+1:0;B(s[e]=!0,m&&"G-F"===o){1e(g u=1;m-1>=u;u++){g f=O(e)+u+""+l;a[f.15()]=!0,s[O(e)+u]=!0}i+=\'<D C="\'+m+\'" z="Z: 0">\'}T i+=\'<D z="Z: 0">\';$.A($.1o({},r.U),7(e,n){g a="";B(a="G-F"===o?K.H(n).q>0&&2 0!==n.5&&2 0!==n.w&&2 0!==t[n.5]:K.H(n).q>0&&2 0!==n.5&&2 0!==n.w&&2 0!==t[n.5]&&n.5===o){g s="Z: 1Q 1K",l=e>0?"1P-1L: 1N":"",d="J: "+t[n.5].R+";"+l+";"+s,r="y.z.J=\'"+t[n.5].1h+"\';",p="y.z.J=\'"+t[n.5].R+"\';",c=n.w.1j("-")[0].1k();i+=\'<9 x="1n" z="\'+d+\'" Y="\'+r+\'" 11="\'+p+\'"><4>\'+n.5+\'</4><9 x="1f"><4 x="w">\'+c+"</4></9></9>"}}),i+="</D>"}"1V"===n&&(i+="</1t>"),6===l&&s[e]===!1&&(i=d),l>=6&&(l=0,d=i)})}),$("#k-j W 1O").I(i)}', 62, 120, '||void||span|type||function|dropdown|div|||||||var|||timetable|sqs||||||length||||||time|class|this|style|each|if|rowspan|td|content|events|all|keys|html|background|Object|on|window|child|parseInt|generateTimeTable|DOMSubtreeModified|bgcolor|callTimeTable|else|multiple|li|table|hash|onmouseover|padding|location|onmouseout|hide|body|return|toString|dropbtn|h3|Events|selected|ul|All|id|arrow|for|timeBox|undefined|bghover|last|split|trim|Parameter|is|dataBox|extend|nth|callTimeTableMobile|console|substr|tr|error|click|bind|off|mouseover|setTimeTable|attr|show|popstate|colorType|text|Configuration|addClass|removeClass|fadeIn|monday|10px|top|mouseout|2px|tbody|margin|14px|toUpperCase|charAt|slice|mobile|saturday'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

Comment: Please fix the script to not give errors (add setTimeTable) and remove enough unnecessary entries to make a [mcve]

Comment: But we don't know any coding. How do we add setimetable? I can remove the classes so it makes it more minimal?

Comment: It’s your code. It’s missing a function - you need to add it

Comment: @FrontlineAcademyNorway Start by removing parts of the table. It's too long and makes it hard to follow

Comment: Okey! I´ll try and make it more friendly on the eyes..

Comment: Removed most of the classes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is function setTimeTable() ?

Comment: I've added `<th>Sunday</th>` and the design didn't break. Seems the problem you're describing is within the external `setTimeTable()` method, which isn't included in your code

Comment: I really wish I could answer your question... or understand it.. I´m sorry..

Comment: The code above is everything we got from the company that made the timetable. They said we could add days/classes by copy and paste in the prefilled timetable. When I add <th>sunday</th> I get another day, but when I try to add classes (copy paste "saturday: [ ]:" and rename to "sunday: [ ]:" the timetable acts up.

Comment: I could not even make your script run without removing the jQuery - you need to move colortabe and config to global slope and possibly use setTimeout for the setTimeTable which lives in the google script in an eval

Comment: I´ve added the javascript. Probably added a lot of unuseful code, but It´s pretty clear that I don´t know what I´m doing :)